# How to apply a function to a Cartesian product efficiently in Python/Numpy?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, lambda, python-itertools

I have a function that I would like to apply on each element of a cartesian product of a linear space. I do know how to do it with functions of one variable that is defined using `lambda`, namely using `map`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
xpts = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
fun = lambda p: p**2
arr = np.array(list(map(fun , xpts)))
```

But with a multivariate function I did not manage to use the `map` function. Here is an example of what I am doing instead, which is slow:

```
def fun(x,y):
    return 2*x+y

xpts = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)

# make dict of indexes
count=0
dic=dict()
for j in xpts:
    dic[j]=count
    count+=1

# preallocate array
arr = np.empty([len(xpts)]*2)

for tup in itertools.product(xpts, xpts):

    ind1 = dic[tup[0]]
    ind2 = dic[tup[1]]

    val1 = tup[0]
    val2 = tup[1]

    arr[ind1, ind2]   = fun(val1, val2)
```

As my function is complicated and the space is large, I am looking for an efficient/scalable way.

Comment: `map` isn't going to make things faster. Optimizing execution of a function in NumPy almost always requires some degree of examining the function's implementation, particularly whether it broadcasts and whether it can be rewritten to broadcast.

Comment: xy = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)... then,  m = np.meshgrid(xy, xy) to get a meshgrid.  You can then use your function with the results of m, like... fun(m[1], m[0]) or swap the results around

Comment: `fun(np.linspace(0, 1, 5)[:,None], np.linspace(0, 1, 10)]` is the most efficient approach - when `fun` is writen so it takes arrays, not scalars.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, just for completeness, I suppose you meant `fun(np.linspace(0, 1, 5)[:,None], np.linspace(0, 1, 5))`

Comment: When broadcastng arrays like that the 2 lengths don't have to match.  In my example the result should be a (5,10) array.